# NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey returning null class

Tags: iphone, nskeyedarchiver

I have an archive which is stored in "Presidents.plist" file. It exist and I can locate it using `pathForResource` method. And also I do get the data using `initWithContentsOfFile` method of `NSData` to retrieve the data. The problem now is in this lines of code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Presidents"
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];
NSData *data; 
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver;
data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
id presidents = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Presidents"];
```

For some reason it is returning a null class instead of my expected NSArray class. Can anyone tell me the reason this is happening and how can I solve this dilemma?

I'm getting the class like this...

```
NSLog(@"presidents class = %@", NSStringFromClass([presidents class]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, [Method 2](http://forum.learncocoa.org/discussion/comment/80/#Comment_80) helped me.

Change the "BIDPresident" to the "President" in Presidents.plist using TextWrangler or try my file http://www.fileswap.com/dl/o29Sxm48g0/Presidents.plist.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object by:

```
    NSMutableDictionary dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archieverPath];
```

archieverPath is the path of the plist.
and you can return the object by

```
return [dict objectForKey:key];
```

Comment: dude!, you're a dude right? I did this `NSMutableDictionary dict = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Presidents"];` and logged it out. The output is `dict = (null)`; On the other hand, the contents of the plist is an array. But then it also returns null.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of iOS the root object of a pList must not be an array.  I had this problem recently.  Try using a dictionary instead.